# angular5, httpclient.post, always get 404

Tags: cors, angular-httpclient

I'm not able to get an Angular5 httpclient.post request to work.  I'm getting a 404 (as seen in chrome devtools) and downstream I get unknown error.  I know my url is good as I can use postman to  do the post and it works fine. I've went around and around with the headers without a good result.  I'm going to a C#/embedded webapi server. https://unosquare.github.io/embedio/

What am i missing here?

```js
 const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    

    const e = eventDescriptor.events[0];

    this._http.post("http://localhost:4000/api/config/setidlestate", e, options)      
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
            },
            error => {
                console.log("Error", error);
            }
        );
```

[image]

Comment: The `Access-Control-*` http headers in your code should be set server side, not client side. Make sure the server can handle OPTIONS requests by enabling Cors

Comment: Will your Postman request work if you use `OPTIONS` instead of `POST`? This is likely a CORS issue as mentioned, but since you're getting a 404 response, this isn't an issue with Angular. I'd recommend posting some of your backend code and adding appropriate tags for your backend.

Comment: I changed it to fetch for this one context i needed and it worked. moving on.